# Solving second-order nonlinear ODE numerically

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

I am trying to solve for the function $p(x)$ which obeys the following:
\begin{align*}
  p\left(x\right) = \left(e^{x} - \frac{1}{2} z \left(p\left(x\right)\right)^2\right)^\gamma \phi(x), \tag{1}
 \end{align*}
    where $\phi(x)$ satisfies
    \begin{align*}
  e^x \left[e^{x} - \frac{1}{2} z \left(p\left(x\right)\right)^2\right]^{-\gamma} = \left[\lambda + (1-\gamma)\delta + \gamma z p(x)\right]\phi(x) - \mathcal A\left(\phi(x) \right), \tag{2}
 \end{align*}
    and $\mathcal A\left(\cdot \right)$ is the infinitesimal generator specified as:
    \begin{align*}
  \mathcal A\left(g(x) \right) = - \theta_x \left(x - \bar x\right)g'(x) + \frac{1}{2} \sigma_x^2 g''(x) \tag{3}
 \end{align*}

I use Python to approximate $p(x)$ with a polynomial and use the optimizer to find the appropriate coefficients, but the optimizer is highly sensitive even on the small range of $x \in [-4.8, -4.2]$ I am looking at, and it converges (or diverges..) to extremely different values depending on the initial guess. I was hoping someone could suggest a proper initial guess for the coefficients as well as an appropriate degree of the polynomial.

An alternative solution is also welcome. I tried to rewrite the problem as a system of equations
\begin{align*}
p(x) = f(p(x), \phi(x)) = \left(e^{x} - \frac{1}{2} z \left(p\left(x\right)\right)^2\right)^\gamma \phi(x) \tag{4}
\end{align*} and 
\begin{align*}
\phi(x) = h(p(x), \phi(x)) = e^{-x}p(x)\bigg(\left[\lambda + (1-\gamma)\delta + \gamma z p(x)\right]\phi(x) - \mathcal A\left(\phi(x) \right)\bigg), \tag{5}
\end{align*}
and then iterate on $f(\cdot)$ and $h(\cdot)$, but neither of them are contractions, so this method doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!